# EC2 ECS Service Autoscaling scaling additional tasks

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs, aws-auto-scaling

I have configured a Target tracking scaling policy for EC2 ECS Service with 50% AverageCPUUtilization. When the ECS Service cross the threshold limit above 50% 2 tasks are getting started in place of 1 task. Is this the actual behaviour or why is it scaling 2 tasks instead of 1?

I have tried with AverageMemoryUtilization metric but the result is the same.

Autoscaling Configuration

[image]
[image]

Comment: So you have 1 task running, and it goes over 50% CPU utilization, so another task is added, for a total of 2 running tasks? Is that correct? Your question is a bit unclear on what specifically is happening.

Comment: I have 1 task running and when utilization goes over 50%, 2 new tasks get added which makes a total of 3 running tasks. Excepted is only 1 task should scale-out.

Comment: Can you show your autoscaling configuration settings?

Comment: @MarkB I have added the autoscaling details.

Comment: 30 seconds seems very low for those cooldown periods. That might be part of the problem. If it is taking more than 30 seconds for the 2nd task to take some of the load off the first task, then it could be adding a third task, which would max our the number of allowed tasks you have configured.

Comment: I have increased the cooldown periods to 300 and still getting the same result.