# ECS EC2 Capacity Provider starting additional EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs, aws-auto-scaling

I provisioned an EC2 ECS cluster using the default capacity provider, which has a base of 0 and a weight of 1. Currently, the minimum and desired count of the Auto Scaling Group (ASG) is set to 0. There is one service with a desired count of 0. When I change the desired count to 1, two instances spin up to run the task, even though the instance has sufficient memory to handle the task.

Ideally, the expected behaviour would be that the capacity provider would increase the ASG desired count to 1. Is this consistent with the expected behaviour of capacity provider-managed scaling?

Comment: I think once you fix your other issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76163001/ec2-ecs-service-autoscaling-scaling-additional-tasks this problem may go away

Comment: The capacity provider is the first feature that I have tested without ecs autoscaling @MarkB

Comment: I had a similar issue that seemed due to `maximumScalingStepSize` greater than 1. Once I set it back to 1 the idle instance was removed.